# Serving static front page using SPDY and nginx

Tags: nginx, spdy

I have a personal website which I recently upgraded to nginx 1.4 series.

I enabled SPDY support, Using the Chrome extension [SPDY indicator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin) I can see that the front page is *not* using SPDY. Once I click on one of the links I can see that SPDY is used.

Is this by design or can I influence this behavior?

This is the corresponding part of the `nginx.conf`:

```
# foo.com (ssl)
server {
    listen 443 ssl spdy;
    listen [::]:443 ssl spdy;
    server_name foo.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/foo.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/foo.com.key;
    # Remember this setting for 365 days
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    root /srv/www/foo.com;
    charset utf-8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at chrome://net-internals I come to the conclusion that the extension *SPDY indicator* does not work as expected. Everything seems to work fine. Firefox also indicates that SPDY is used at the front page.